# How to prevent tikzexternalize to generate files in current directory?

Tags: tikz-pgf, pdftex, tikz-external

I'm using pdflatex. I'm building in a "build" subdirectory with the --output-directory of pdflatex and it works really well, every file is generated in this directory.

Now, I want to externalize my pgfplots, so I'm using:

```
\usetikzlibrary{external}
\tikzexternalize[shell escape=-enable-write1 -shell-escape, prefix=./build/]
```

In that case, the external files are created in the build directory (the MD5 files are created in the build/build, but it does not matter). However, after this, several files are created in the working directory rather than in the build directory. After the build, I have these files:

> master.acn
>     master.glo
>     master.ist
>     master.maf
>     master.mw
>     master.run.xml

in the working directory rather than in the build directory :(

I know that these files are not related to tikz, but they only appear here when I use tikzexternalize.

Why is tikzexternalize creating some extra files in the current working directory ? Is it possible to get rid of these files ?

Thanks

Comment: You should make a complete example. You should also mention your tex system.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think the most straightforward way to do this is not to set `prefix` at all but to instead do two things.

1. Ensure that `--output-directory` is passed to the compiler when it is run by the externalisation process by overriding the default compilation command.

   - This should ensure that *all* files generated when producing the externalised images are written to `build/` and not only those directly concerned with externalisation.
2. Ensure that Ti*k*Z searches in the correct place for the externalised images by overriding the default image inclusion command.

   - This should ensure TeX looks in the correct place for the externalised images  by directly manipulating the path used when including images rather than by setting `prefix`. `prefix` won't work here because it will also be used when externalising, creating an unwanted cumulative effect when producing images (`build/build/<image>`) but not when including them (`build/<image>`), resulting in errors.

For example, you might want something like this (based on the information in your question and the default explained on page 609 of the Ti*k*Z manual and the information on page 616):

```
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@article{author-art,
  author              =   {Author, A. N.},
  title               =   {Believe It or Not \dots},
  volume              =   290,
  year                =   3056,
  doi                 =   {44.897/gje.x789},
  pages               =   {x789},
  eprinttype          =   {gje},
  eprint              =   {x789},
  eprintclass         =   {290},
  journal             =   {Greatest Journal Ever}}
@article{author-anart,
  author              =   {Author, A. N.},
  title               =   {Suppose It or Not \dots},
  volume              =   78,
  number              =   3,
  year                =   3049,
  pages               =   {22--29},
  eprinttype          =   {jstor},
  eprint              =   {12980258},
  journal             =   {Second Best Journal Ever}}
\end{filecontents}

\documentclass[british]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[backend=biber]{biblatex}
\bibliography{\jobname}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{external}
\tikzexternalize
\tikzset{%
  external/system call={pdflatex \tikzexternalcheckshellescape --halt-on-error --interaction=batchmode --output-directory=./build --jobname "\image" "\texsource"},
  /pgf/images/include external/.code={%
    \includegraphics{build/#1}%
  },
}
\begin{document}
\Textcite{author-art,author-anart}

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \draw (0,0) rectangle (1,1);
\end{tikzpicture}

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

I then compiled with

```
pdflatex --shell-escape --output-directory=./build <filename>.tex 
biber --output-directory=./build <filename>
pdflatex --shell-escape --output-directory=./build <filename>.tex
```

This generated all files in `build/` and seemed to compile successfully, using the externalised image rather than recompiling the Ti*k*Z code on the second run.

[image: result]

Comment: I think I'm almost there with your solution. The problem with that solution is that the PDF of the figures are generated in build/build but are searched by tikz in build/ and are therefore not found. If I create a symbolic link build/build -> build/ it works... It is weird that you don't have this problem

Comment: @BaptisteWicht I just realised that you said you are externalising pgfplots. If you are using `pgfplots`, you should probably use its externalisation facilities. (I don't think this is the solution to your problem, but just a side-note.) I'll try to look at this again later - it certainly seemed to work for me, but maybe I did something in experimenting which just made it appear that way.

Comment: @BaptisteWicht Hmmm... Now I can't even get it to compile. I wonder what I did before ...

Comment: @BaptisteWicht Please see edit above. I *think* this version works - please test and let me know.

Answer (score 3):

The files you list are mostly unrelated to tikz, `.glo` is your document glossary, `.ist` is a makeindex style, and `.run.xml` is generated by biblatex.

Comment: I think `acn` is also glossaries related. The `maf` though, no idea.

Comment: I know that they are unrelated. But they only appear in the working directory if I use tikzexternalize. Otherwise, they are simply inside the build directory.