# Getting a valid makefile from tikz-externalize when using `-output-directory` and input

Tags: tikz-pgf, pdftex, external-files, makefile, externalize

The following mwe does produce an invalid makefile when used with `latexmk`'s `-output-directory` option. (The example is from the `pgfplots` manual)

`latexmk mwe.tex -output-directory=build`

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepgfplotslibrary{external}
\tikzexternalize[mode=list and make]

\begin{document}

\input{tikz/figure.tikz}

\end{document}
```

and a file under `tikz/figure.tikz`

```
\begin{figure}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}
\addplot {x^2};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\caption{Our first external graphics example}
\end{figure}
```

with the makefile beeing at `build/mwe.makefile`

```
ALL_FIGURE_NAMES=$(shell cat mwe.figlist)
ALL_FIGURES=$(ALL_FIGURE_NAMES:%=%.pdf)

allimages: $(ALL_FIGURES)
    @echo All images exist now. Use make -B to re-generate them.

FORCEREMAKE:

include $(ALL_FIGURE_NAMES:%=%.dep)

%.dep:
    mkdir -p "$(dir $@)"
    touch "$@" # will be filled later.

mwe-figure0.pdf: 
    pdflatex -shell-escape -halt-on-error -interaction=batchmode -jobname "mwe-figure0" "\def\tikzexternalrealjob{mwe}\input{mwe}"

mwe-figure0.pdf: mwe-figure0.md5
```

as the `mwe.tex` file is not in the `build` directory, running the `make` command from the `build` directory will not work;
also running it from the projcts "root" directory will not work, as there is no `mwe.figlist` there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This solution is a dirty hack, so I will not accept it, hoping for someone to provide a better answer.

A current workaround I have is modifying the commands used to create the makefile; this idea is from [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/333960/how-to-prevent-tikzexternalize-to-generate-files-in-current-directory) and modify the commands including moving up a directory **`cd .. &&`** and setting the output-directory **`--output-directory=./build`** as follows:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepgfplotslibrary{external}
\tikzexternalize[mode=list and make]

\tikzset{%
    external/system call={cd .. && pdflatex \tikzexternalcheckshellescape --halt-on-error --interaction=batchmode --output-directory=./build --jobname "\image" "\texsource"},
    /pgf/images/include external/.code={%
        \includegraphics{build/#1}%
    },
}
\begin{document}

\input{tikz/figure.tikz}

\end{document}
```

generating the new makefile

```
ALL_FIGURE_NAMES=$(shell cat mwe.figlist)
ALL_FIGURES=$(ALL_FIGURE_NAMES:%=%.pdf)

allimages: $(ALL_FIGURES)
        @echo All images exist now. Use make -B to re-generate them.

FORCEREMAKE:

include $(ALL_FIGURE_NAMES:%=%.dep)

%.dep:
        mkdir -p "$(dir $@)"
        touch "$@" # will be filled later.

mwe-figure0.pdf: 
        cd .. && pdflatex -shell-escape --halt-on-error --interaction=batchmode --output-directory=./build --jobname "mwe-figure0" "\def\tikzexternalrealjob{mwe}\input{mwe}"

mwe-figure0.pdf: mwe-figure0.md5
```

which now can be built from the `build` directory with `make -f mwe.makefile`.