# Tikz externalization output-dir on two levels

Tags: tikz-pgf, xetex, tikz-external, format-files

I'm trying to get a nice dir structure for my project but I'm having lots of trouble with externalization. I've read many questions but the most accurate for my case is this [question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/333960/how-to-prevent-tikzexternalize-to-generate-files-in-current-directory). The problem is that when using just the `./build` output dir works fine but no with sub-directories `.build/Pictures` for example.

My main compilation scheme is:

```tex
xelatex -synctex=1 -interaction=nonstopmode --shell-escape --output-directory=./build %.tex
```

I'm trying to get a sub-directory dedicated for tikz externalization outputs inside `./build` this way.

```tex
\tikzset{%
    external/system call={%
        xelatex \tikzexternalcheckshellescape --output-directory ./build/Pictures/ -halt-on-error -interaction=batchmode -jobname "\image" "\texsource"%
    },
    /pgf/images/include external/.code={%
        \includegraphics{build/Pictures/#1}%
    }
}
```

I noticed that:

- Using only `./build` directory works
- When adding `./build/Pictures` it searches the pdf file on **root** (I found that it worked when I copied-pasted the PDF on root)

Why does it work when using a single level but no with multiple levels?

## MWE

```tex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{external}
\tikzexternalize
\tikzset{%
  external/system call={xelatex \tikzexternalcheckshellescape --halt-on-error --interaction=batchmode --output-directory=./build/Pictures --jobname "\image" "\texsource"},
  /pgf/images/include external/.code={%
    \includegraphics{build/Pictures/#1}%
  },
}
\begin{document}

Hello im having trouble

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \draw (0,0) rectangle (1,1);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: I never use `--output-directory`. If I want to keep the source folder clean, I use l3build to move all files before the compilation to a dedicated build folder. See also https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/673007/2388